# INA301 current sense amp for milliamps detection

Tags: current, current-measurement

I want to detect the amount of current that flows through a shunt resistor. When the current exceeds a known value it must then turn on a 5V DC buzzer.

The current limit is 30mA. So if the current exceeds 30mA then the buzzer is activated.

The voltage across the shunt resistor can range from 2V up to 60V DC. In addition, the "ground" of the shunt resistor is floating. The "floating ground" is connected to a metal enclosure. Hence I basically want to know if the current is flowing through the metal enclosure (i.e the source ground is now connected to the metal enclosure). Normal working conditions will not have any current flowing through it. The metal enclosure should be isolated from the 3V to 60V source.

**I know the second condition is what happens when the 3V to 60V DC is also connected to the metal enclosure, however, I am only dealing with the source ground to the metal enclosure for now.**

I came across the INA301A3 ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina301.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1645348145848&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fina301)), which is a current sense amplifier with an integrated comparator.

From the specs, I would use a 1-ohm shunt resistor. Hence The INA301A1 has a gain of 100 so the
resulting output voltage at the 30-mA input condition is 3V (30mA x 1-ohm x 100). Therefore the Rlimit resistance is 37.5kohm.

My questions are:

Did I select the correct IC for my application stated above?

DO I need to isolate the buck/boost supply and hence can the GND of the INA301 IC to the isolated ground of the buck/boost? (The buck/boost isolated ground is different from the metal enclosure isolated gound).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu6AzB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Do you have different grounds completely NOT referenced to one another in your circuit (i.e. effectively floating)? How can you imagine 30mA if you have some 50V supply applied to 1 Ohm or 10 Ohm? I also have a feeling zeners will totally mess up your readings. I think you need to take a step back

Comment: @Ilya the metal enclosure is not a separate ground, I made an error in the names. It is just a wire that is tapped onto the metal enclosure and can be connected to the battery's ground, through a pinched battery ground cable. The zeners are recommended by the manufacturer, see page 20, fig. 41.

Comment: You totally misunderstood the purpose of zeners here. They way you put them there, they will only totally ruin measurements. You're not supposed to apply more than 35V volts to whatever is measured

Comment: @Ilya I see, will clamping diodes help instead of zeners?

Comment: No. They won't. You need to change the entire circuit. This chip will not work with supply over 35V no matter what you do. The only thing you measure above 35V is manufacturing differences between zeners or whatever other diodes you put there.

Comment: @Ilya I will just use a potential divider then to drop the voltage to below 35V before is goes to the INA301

Comment: And you measurement will be ruined by divider tolerance. But if your point is to detect short, it will do, but only if you make sure the voltage on positive side is always larger (if you're unlucky with tolerances, it can be different). Also, if you just need a short detect, you don't really need a whole current sense amp. Just a comparator would be enough with a pair of voltage dividers around

Comment: You should take a look at the INA20x (INA 201, INA 202 ...) which has an 80V common mode range. The INA301 has only a 35V range which won't work here.

Comment: @RandyNuss never mind, this will definitely work, I was searching for the wrong part number...

Comment: @RandyNuss the INA301 can still work, just need to the current biasing resistors on the voltage divider to drop the voltage in the 0 to 36V range.

Answer (score 0):

If the metal enclosure GND is isolated from the source/buck boost/INA301 GND, there will be no current flow. The mentioned circuits need a common GND to operate.

It sounds like you are describing a fault current detection device, similar to RCDs. If you can't work with a traditional RCD then maybe you could use a current transformer, if you want to work with an isolated source.

Comment: I see my naming is completely wrong. The metal enclosure is not ground, sorry about that. So the metal enclosure 'can' be connected to the battery's ground (either through a pinched battery ground cable or some other means), which I do not want. It should always be isolated (never connected to the source).

Comment: @JoeyB if your enclosure isn't connected to anything, then it is effectively an open line. Disconnected wire. So it won't act like any kind of ground at all. Its voltage will be equal to supply voltage.

Comment: @Ilya yes I know it is a disconnected line, but my circuit is to detect when the open line becomes a closed line when the metal enclosure is connected to the battery's ground.

Comment: @JoeyB Ok, that's what I thought you were looking for and I that's why I figured it might be for fault current detection. 1 Ohm sounds unnecessarily small? Do you want to detect other faults too like a IO or positive voltage shorting to the enclosure?

Comment: I mean maybe you could just connect the chassis to logic high (+5 V or what ever you are using) on purpose through a 100 kohm resistor and read the enclosure voltage. If the chassis might be at 60 V too it's better to read with something fault tolerant, like a resistor + TVS protected GPIO.

Comment: @Ralph I also forget to add a load resistor, which I have done now. I just need to detect when the enclosure gets grounded, however I see the INA301 IC can be made bidirectional by using two of them. So this will allow me to detect positive volatge aswell

Comment: @Ralph are there any reasons why you would not want to use this IC, it is quite cheap and there is a lot of them.

Comment: The chip is ok, but you'll have trouble with the zener protection you currently have in the circuit and you need to figure out a way to keep the voltage low enough for the IC.

Comment: @Ralph I did want to implement a resistor divider, keeping the output of this resistor divider to 30V max for input of 60V. Are there any other ways